# Why doesn't TAB indent C++ Code in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, indentation

I believe this is not standard behavior, but when I press the TAB key immediately before or after a variable or constant, Visual Studio will not indent the code using tab spacing.  Instead, it highlights the value with a pink underscore and advances to the next instance of that value.  If I continue to press TAB, I will rotate through all the instances of that value/variable within the current scope.

I have not been able to find a setting that turns this auto-search style behavior off and return back to simple indentation.  Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.  Frankly, I'm starting to lose my mind....

Rich

Comment: Do you have any extensions installed? You could try disabling / removing them.

Comment: I don't think so, but how exactly would I determine if any extensions are installed?

Comment: Worth noting that this other question had the solution I was after: http://superuser.com/questions/428790/tab-key-not-working-in-vs2010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard behavior is as you desire; i.e. TAB indents (and shift-TAB un-indents).  You may have an extension installed that's messing it up.  Or perhaps you inadvertently remapped the key binding.  Or perhaps when you installed you selected an editing environment that uses a different key binding map (I always choose C++).

Comment: I only have one extension installed, DevExpress Tools version 11.2.11.  I'll try uninstalling that, but I need to make sure I still have all the stuff to install that later.  I need it for another project.

Comment: After uninstalling the DevExpress Tools extension, the problem goes away.  So, now I need to reinstall that tools and test if the problem returns.  If so, I need to focus on those tools and any settings provided by them to find the cause of the problem.  At least I know which vendor to focus on.